# Is it possible to use the Synopse SynPDF library to View a PDF file?

Tags: delphi, pdf

I've come across the [excellent PDF Library code SynPDF](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=PDF%20Engine) and would like to use it to display a PDF document in a Delphi form (I cant use an imported 'Acrobat Control for ActiveX' control because it has issues with stealing the focus when it appears - plus a few other wrinkles). I cannot see any 'LoadFromFile' or indeed any parsing-type commands within SynPDF.pas. It is designed only for creating PDF documents?

Comment: Why don't you contact the component author directly? Seems more effective than asking here.

Comment: @Marjan: Well it is such a useful (and free) demonstration of code that I felt that SO would benefit from links to it.

Comment: Ah, a hidden agenda :-)) Good on you. And +1 for kindness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've answered [in our forum your question you posted there](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=416). It's the first place to ask for such dedicated answer IMHO.

Here is my answer (for SO users):

> The purpose of this library is to create pdf file from scratch, not
> read, modify or view them. Sorry.
>
> So you'll have to use an external
> viewer, like Acrobat Reader Active X. Or some commercial libraries
> like [this one](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/pdfviewer/index.htm).

Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. I should have waited for the reply. The code is very stimulating though, and now I'm looking at SynCommons for other ideas.

Comment: While not a PDF viewer, but does have PDF rending support so that you could create your own, you may wish to consider http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/